# Reference request: No consistent ordering of triangles for an arrangement of four lines

Tags: general-topology, geometry, reference-request

Suppose $l_1$, $l_2$, $l_3$, and $l_4$ are lines such that each pair of lines meets at a point and no three lines meet at a point. Each triple of lines, for example $l_1$, $l_2$, $l_3$ then defines a triangle. If we orient each line so that we have a well defined positive direction, then one of these triangles is consistent with the orientation if the direction of the lines supporting the sides of the triangle give us a consistent direction either counter-clockwise or clockwise around the triangle.

It is clearly not possible to orient all the lines so that every triangle defined by any three of the four lines is consistently oriented around its triangle.

This seems to me that it must be a well known theorem, so my question is whose theorem is it and where can I find it?